# How to add image to navigation bar

Tags: html, css

How to add image to navigation bar

```
<div id="navigation">
<ul>
    <li><a href="index.html">მთავარი</a></li>
    <li><a href="articles.html">სტატიები</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">კონტაქტი</a></li>
    <li><a href="about.html">პროექტის შესახებ</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

css:

```css
li {
    display: inline;
}

#navigation {
    display: inline;
    background-image: url("navbar.png");
}
```

Comment: Where do you want the image to appear? As an item in the list?

Comment: as a background image

Comment: a different background image per item or one for the entire menu?

Comment: I love "css:enter code here" : you want us to enter code here ? try by yourself and then we will be there to help !

Comment: nooo it just didn't appear  :  li{
 
 
 display: inline;
}

#navigation{
display: inline;
background-image: url("navbar.png");

Comment: To get answers (and no down votes) for the question, explain your problem well, edit the question to make it more clear. And about your question, is your image in the correct location?

Comment: thank you. yes it is, I tested it on body and it works

Answer (score 0):

```
    #navigation ul li a{
      background: url(../images/bg_common_03.png) no-repeat 0 0;
    }
```

Try this